# Python 3.x - How to check if "From:" header exists in an email file?

Tags: python-3.x

Since `has_keys()` function is removed in Python 3 and above, I don't know what code to use to check if a "From: " header exist in an email file.

Here is my current snippet:

```py
with open(emlFile, 'rb') as fp:
        headers = BytesParser(policy=policy.default).parse(fp)
        if 'From:' in headers:
            str = headers['from']
```

I used `in` instead of `has_keys('from')` since that is what I saw from other threads in StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting official Python docs (**emphasis** mine):

[`BytesParser.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#email.parser.BytesParser.parse):

> Read all the data from the binary file-like object fp, parse the
>   resulting bytes, and **return the message object**. fp must support both
>   the readline() and the read() methods on file-like objects.

Since result of parse is `Message` instance, let's check [that class docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.__contains__):

`__contains__(name)`:

> Return true if the message object has a field
>   named name. Matching is done case-insensitively and **name should not
>   include the trailing colon**. Used for the in operator, e.g.:

```
if 'message-id' in myMessage:
   print('Message-ID:', myMessage['message-id'])
```

Your check includes trailing colon and is invalid according to docs. Valid check is:

```
if 'from' in headers:
    do_something()
```